# react.development.js and Uncaught ReferenceError: useState is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get some React code to work. I need to work with `react.development.js` and not React on the server side. I am trying to solve a different issue and I wanted to use `useState` for that, but this fails.

The start of my page has:

```html
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and much of React works. But when I try to use `useState`, e.g. in:

```
        const ReminderSet = () => {
            console.log( "Reminderset Rendering");
            const [reminders, setReminders] = useState(defaultReminder);
```

I get an error in the console, e.g. in Firefox:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: useState is not defined
```

Comment: `React.useState(...)`, perhaps? What exactly do you mean _"much of React works"_?

Comment: I have stuff that displays and I can interact with it. My problem is that I am talking to something that is not a real web server, I have a service that provides a page and two GET/POST entries. So, everything react is client-side. And that service provides data I need in my component. So, without getting the data from the service and faking it, stuff works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

`useState` isn't a global, it's A) a property of the `React` object, and B) a named export from the `react` module. I suggest switching to using modules, in which case you can do `import { useState } from "react";`. But if you don't want to do that, you can use `React.useState` or `const { useState } = React;` and then use `useState` directly.

#### Using modules:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => setCounter((c) => c + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            Count: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick={increment} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Live copy (using Babel standalone, which is why the script tag has an unusual type; don't use Babel standalone, use a bundler like Vite or Rollup or Webpack [or alternatively, don't use JSX]):

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-3" data-type="module">
import React, { useState } from "https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0";
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom@18.2.0";

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => setCounter((c) => c + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            Count: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick={increment} />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);

</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.2/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>
```

#### Not using modules:

```
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => setCounter((c) => c + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            Count: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick={increment} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Live example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => setCounter((c) => c + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            Count: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" value="+" onClick={increment} />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. If I use `const [reminders, setReminders] = React.useState(defaultReminder);` can I simply call setReminders() globally?

Comment: @gctwnl - Not globally, but throughout the component function where you've done that, yes.

Comment: I've refactored both components into a single one as a the fastest solution to have a single useState for everything. It works now (after some more small issues). Thanks.